# Prove: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Prove: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\geq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$ for all x, y positive

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{x\sqrt{x}+y\sqrt{y}-x\sqrt{y}-y\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})-y(-\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{(x-y)(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

$$\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$

All the elements are positive and if $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$ we get $0$

Is the proof valid?

Comment: @6005 yes, sorry, I will add

Comment: Yes, the proof is valid. Perhaps when working backwards, you should enounce it at the beginning. For instance "we want check that this inequality is true for all $x,y>0$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be positive, then I do not see anything wrong, but I think it would be *much* better if you rewrote it from the bottom up instead of as you have it now (working *from* what you are trying to prove as opposed to *to* it, if that makes sense).

Comment: Also, this is in fact not a chain of impliations, but just a chain of equations, i.e., this could be rewritten as the (long) "one-liner" $\frac x{\sqrt y}+\frac y{\sqrt x}-\sqrt x-\sqrt y=\ldots=\frac{(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)^2(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)}{\sqrt x\sqrt y}\ge 0$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, the inclusion of $\geq0$ every time is rather unnecessary. I think it would be best to have the chain of equations with a simple note about $\geq0$ at the outset.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, apply AM-GM inequality with $a = \sqrt{x}, b = \sqrt{y}$:

$\dfrac{a^2}{b} + b \geq 2\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b}\cdot b} = 2a, \dfrac{b^2}{a} + a \geq 2\sqrt{\dfrac{b^2}{a}\cdot a} = 2b$. Adding these $2$ inequalities to get the answer.

**Generalization**: The same technique could be used to prove: If $x, y, z > 0 \implies \dfrac{x^2}{y} + \dfrac{y^2}{z} + \dfrac{z^2}{x} \geq x+y+z$.

Comment: I am having hard time to see AM-GM inequality I do see that the inequalities come from $(a-b)^2\geq 0$

Comment: Just edit it...

Comment: For learning purpose, how did you get to  $\dfrac{a^2}{b} + b \geq 2\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b}\cdot b} $? or more precise how did you think about this form of AM-GM inequality?

Comment: Two reasons: $1)$: it comes with time..., $2)$: you want to get rid of the bottom $b$, hence you need to add $b$ so the AM-GM takes care of the $b$'s for ya...Also, I would say that if you want to be strong in proving inequalities, you need to learn to manipulate the square-root, cube-root, and fractions really well. Holder inequality requires this skill.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Titus lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/):
$$\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}b\ge \frac{(x+y)^2}{a+b}$$
Then $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}^2}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{\sqrt{y}^2}{\sqrt{x}}\ge \frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$

Comment: I do not understand how does it help

Comment: @gbox: I edited

Comment: How is this inequality called?

Comment: @gbox titu's lemma

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/

Answer (score 1):

First you neeed to qualify your starting point by saying that $x,y > 0$ and that by $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{y}$ the proposition means the positive value of that square root.  But these are tirival details.

The second flaw is that what you presented is not a proof; the very first line of the "proof" asserts the proposition that was to have been proven.  The steps you present are a very good way to discover the steps of the proof, but the proof itself would have to start with your last step and work its way upwards.  Thus:
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 \geq 0 \wedge (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}) \geq 0 \wedge \sqrt{y}\sqrt{x} > 0 \implies 
\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x}}\geq 0$$
should have been the first step, not the last.  From there you go to your next-to-last step, and onward till you have reached the proposition to be proven.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid, but I suggest an alternative.

Let $a=\sqrt{x}>0$ and $b=\sqrt{y}>0$. You want to show
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}\ge a+b
$$
which becomes
$$
\frac{a^3+b^3}{ab}\ge a+b
$$
or
$$
\frac{(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)}{ab}\ge a+b
$$
Since $a+b>0$ and $ab>0$, we can factor out $a+b$ and remove the denominator, so the inequality becomes
$$
a^2-ab+b^2\ge ab
$$

Can you finish?

---

Your strategy works as well: the inequality is equivalent to
$$
\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}-a-b\ge0
$$
that becomes
$$
\frac{a^3+b^3-ab(a+b)}{ab}\ge0
$$
The numerator can be rewritten as
$$
a^3+b^3-ab(a+b)=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)-ab(a+b)=
(a+b)(a-b)^2
$$
So the inequality is
$$
\frac{(a+b)(a-b)^2}{ab}\ge0
$$
which is true.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way, by eliminating at once the square roots.

Setting $x=X^2$ and $y=Y^2$ with $X>0$ and $Y>0$, the issue is equivalent to:

$$\text{show that} \ \ \ \dfrac{X^2}{Y}+\dfrac{Y^2}{X} \geq X+Y$$

which amounts to prove that:

$$X^3+Y^3 \geq XY(X+Y)$$

knowing factorization $X^3+Y^3=(X+Y)(X^2-XY+Y^2)$ and simplifying by $X+Y$, one is brought back to show that $X^2-2XY+Y^2 \geq 0$ i.e. $(X-Y)^2\geq 0$ which is eviedently true.